# If I delete my answer, what happens to points?

Tags: support, answer-quality, deleted-answers

If I delete my answer, what happens to the points that have been added/subtracted from my reputation?

I do not see an answer to this when I do a search in the help section.

Comment: There's a post on main meta that I hope someone who's not using mobile can find and link. Look for "what happens when a post is deleted" and "is it kosher to delete".

Comment: When I search from those in the meta page's search nothing topic comes up at all (0 results). Maybe I'm in the wrong search box? I then tried "delete post reputation points" and nothing relevant came up.

Comment: see [When is it kosher to delete one's own answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216846/312691)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get back the points that were substracted from your reputation. [As the FAQ says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/312691) (in the section *What does deletion mean for a post?*)

> Reputation changes from bounties, votes (both up and down), and
>   acceptances on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question)
>   are nullified.

See there for exceptions.

Comment: That link did the trick. I wonder why searching didn't produce any relevant links?

Comment: @curls did you search here on Mi Yodeya meta or on main meta (meta.stackexchange.com)? The presence of more than one site might have confused you; the other site has questions that apply all across the SE network.

Comment: I was on mi yodeya and went to help and that led to meta. I never went to other stack sites for this search.

Comment: Can I comment to a moderator who's commented on my question, AFTER it was deleted? I can't add a comment to him. I want to tell him to look at the chat, where I replied to him.

Comment: @curls no but you can ping him on the main chat directly: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam by writing @ and the moderator name then your message

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.